# ManyToOne not persisted

Tags: java, hibernate

@OneToMany side of the relation populates well but the @ManyToOne side overrides each time(only the last item persists)

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name="order")
    public class Order {

        @Id
        @Column(name ="orderId")
        private String orderId;
          @OneToMany(targetEntity = Items.class,
          fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
          @JoinColumn(name = "orderId")
          @NotNull
          private Set<Items> items;
        .......
    }
    @Entity
    public class Items {

    @Id
    private String itemId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="orderId",referencedColumnName = "orderId")
    private Order order;
    ............
}
```

Comment: Please share code on how you persist if the answer you got doesn't fix it (_hint:_ only persist the order, not the items, cascading does that for you)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="order")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @Column(name ="orderId")
    private String orderId;
      @OneToMany(targetEntity = Items.class,
      fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL
      ,mappedBy = "item_id")
      @NotNull
      private Set<Items> items;
    .......
}
@Entity
public class Items {

@Id
private String itemId;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="orderId",referencedColumnName = "orderId")
private Order order;
............
```

Comment: I get this exception : nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property:

Answer (score 0):

Replace **targetEntity = Items.class** by  **mappedBy = "order"** 
and remove **referencedColumnName = "orderId"** and **@JoinColumn(name = "orderId")** from OneToMany.

Also if you really need eager fetching delete it from OneToMany side - ManyToOne is eager by default.